# Break HTML content after every 2 words

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to break **HTML** content after every 2 words using **CSS** and make it work for each possible word.

```
Example:

// Current HTML content
The community is here

// Expected outcome:
The community
is here
```

Comment: This is not a "responsive" behaviour since it does not adapt to the display. You can achieve this result using javascript to edit the strings by inserting breakline characters every two words.

Comment: CSS is not going to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not suggest using **CSS** in this case.

Example of how you could achieve it with **regex**:

```js
let text = 'The community is here';
// Regex for linebreak after each second space.
let lineBreakText = text.replace(/^((\S+\s+){1}\S+)\s+/, '$1<br>');
let element = document.getElementById('example');
element.innerHTML = lineBreakText;
```

```html
<div id="example"></div>
```

**S+** matches one or more non-space characters. **\s+** matches one or more space characters. It will add a `<br>`tag for each second word.